# Changing date format in Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have this Excel data:

[image]

Using this formula:

```
="select '"&J4&"_"&H4&"', DATE '"&K3&"', DATE '"&K4&"' union all"
```

I get:

[image]

But I need both dates in this format:

[image]

I bolded the format of date I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Text formula:

```
Text(K3,"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

So `&K3&`

Becomes

```
&Text(K3,"YYYY-MM-DD")&
```

Do same for K4

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the functions YEAR() MONTH() and DAY() then put them in the format you want?
If k3 has the date, then YEAR(k3) will give 2017 etc

Comment: This is better suited as a comment if it's just a suggestion as opposed to a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `&K3&` for the following:

```
&SUBSTITUTE(K3,"/","-")&
```